# Do you know this form of an uncertainty principle?

Tags: fourier-analysis, inequalities, mp.mathematical-physics

I hope this question is focused enough – it's not about real problem I have, but to find out if anyone knows about a similar thing.

You probably know the [Heisenberg uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle): For any function $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ for which the respective expressions exist it holds that
$$ 
\frac{1}{4}\|g\|_2^4 \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} |x|^2 |g(x)|^2 \,dx \int_{\mathbb{R}} |g'(x)|^2 \,dx.
$$

This inequality is not only important in quantum mechanics, but also in signal processing for the short-time Fourier transform, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle).

One can derive this by formally using integration by parts
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} 1\,|g(x)|^2\, dx = -\int_{\mathbb{R}} x\tfrac{d}{dx}|g(x)|^2\,dx \leq 2\int_{\mathbb{R}} |xg(x)|\,|g'(x)|\,dx
$$
and Cauchy–Schwarz.

Now, changing just the order of the functions, you obtain this inequality
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} |g(x)|^2 \, dx  \leq 2\int_{\mathbb{R}} |xg'(x)|\,|g(x)| \, dx
\leq \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} |xg'(x)|^2 \, dx\right)^{1/2} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} |g(x)|^2 \, dx\right)^{1/2}
$$
which gives
$$
\|g\|_2\leq \|xg'\|_2.
$$

Ok, this was just playing around. However, this inequality can also be motivated by an abstract consideration about uncertainty principle associated to group-related integral transforms (see my [two](https://regularize.wordpress.com/2011/09/16/the-uncertainty-principle-for-the-windowed-fourier-transform/) [blog
posts](https://regularize.wordpress.com/2011/09/20/the-uncertainty-principle-for-the-one-dimensional-wavelet-transform/)). Interestingly, the Heisenberg uncertainty principle derives from the short time Fourier transform and the last "uncertainty principle" derives from the wavelet transform.

The last fact bothers me: In contrast to the fact that both inequalities can be derived from two conceptually very different integral transforms (indeed both underlying groups are very different), they have a very similar formal derivation.

I have the following questions: Is anyone familiar with the last inequality? Could it be useful in any context? Is there some reason why these inequalities seem so entangled?

Comment: Isn't the last inequality (I assume you meant $\|g\|_2 \leq \|xg'\|_2$) just a manifestation of Hardy's inequality? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality In which case, yes, people are familiar with it. 

Comment: In 1D Hardy's inequality is a bit awkward to express and you should work with functions vanishing at zero to get a neat formulation. Of course you can go from one to the other and back, but I would not say it is an instant consequence

Comment: @Dirk Naive question: in the RHS of your main inequaliity, arein't the first and second integral equal to one another ? Indeed, $$\int_{\mathbb R}|x|^2|f( x)|^2\,dx = \int_{\mathbb R}|(\widehat{f})'(z)|^2\,dz =  \int_{\mathbb R}|\widehat{f'}(z)|^2\,dz = \|\widehat{f'}\|_{L^2}^2 = \|f'\|_{L^2}^2.$$

Comment: There is no hat in the integrals. The first is the variance of $g$ while the second is (proportional to) the variance of $\hat g$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exists a plethora of inequalities relating weighted $L^p$ norms of a function and its derivatives. For instance you have the Caffarelli-Kohn-Nirenberg family of inequalities
$$\| |x|^{-\gamma}u\|_ {L^{r}}\le C \||x|^{-\alpha}\nabla u\|^{a}_ {L^{p}}\||x|^{-\beta}u\|^{1-a}_ {L^{q}}
$$
which hold for a quite large range of parameters; note that here $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ may assume negative values. You will not have difficulty in googling the vast literature on the subject (let me add that there is a recent paper of mine on arXiv with some improvements on this).

Comment: Wow, there are lot of constants involved. As far as I've seen, it seems that the case $\gamma=0$, $a=1$ and $\alpha=-1$ is not included?

Comment: You can take $n=1,a=1/2,\beta=\gamma=0,\alpha=-1$ to get your inequality, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: I got a little bit confused with all these different inequalities around (many of them called Caffarelli-Kohn-Nirenberg) but now I see. That's an interesting relation though. The Heisenberg uncertainty is also included? ($\gamma=\alpha=0$, $\beta=−1$, $a=1/2$) 

Comment: Yes indeed, and it's not limited to the $L^2$ framework as you see

Answer (score 0):

I find the neatest "standard" uncertainty principle is the one with commutators, see e.g. http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/751.mf1i.fall02/GenUncertPrinciple.htm. I think that readily gives both your inequalities.

Comment: Of course the first one is an instance of the abstract "Robinson's uncertainty principle". However, for the second it's not that straightforward...